# javascript toLowerCase() function returns different string

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log("HİNDİ".toLocaleLowerCase() == "hindi");
console.log("HİNDİ" == "hindi");

console.log("HİNDİ".toLowerCase());


console.log("HİNDİ".toLocaleLowerCase())
console.log("HİNDİ".toLowerCase())
```

I am building a search functionality  but i come across a thing:

```
"HİNDİ".toLocaleLowerCase() // "hindi"

"hindi" == "HİNDİ".toLocaleLowerCase() //false
```

What the heck is going on here?

**Solution:**
@pmrotule's answer seems to work:

```
function to_lower(s)
{
    var n = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) // do it for one character at a time
    {
        var c = s[i].toLowerCase();

        // call replace() only if the character has a length > 1
        // after toLowerCase()
        n += c.length > 1 ? c[0].replace(/[^ -~]/g,'') : c;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Different encoding on the strings? Javascript uses UTF-16 internally. You could run `"HİNDİ".toLocaleLowerCase()` in your console. Also, you can try to type the character code directly. Example: `"\u90AB"`

Comment: Both UTF8, You may try it on the console too here on stackowerflow. Same result.

Comment: Make sure you have this in the `<head>` section of your HTML file: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` (HTML5) or for HTML4: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;UTF-8">`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in a snippet (it says `true`). If you can, then please include the snippet in the question.

Comment: The current code in the updated question gives me `true, false, hindi, hindi, hindi`. No problem for me. Possibly locale dependent.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent("HİNDİ".toLocaleLowerCase())`

Comment: Seems to be browser dependent as well. For me the problem occurs in IE, not in FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a problem of string format. `toLocaleLowerCase` is meant for human-readable display only. However, there is still a trick you can do:

```
if ("hindi" == "HİNDİ".toLowerCase().replace(/[^ -~]/g,''))
{
    alert("It works!");
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to make it works with all special characters:

```js
function to_lower(s)
{
    var n = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) // do it for one character at a time
    {
        var c = s[i].toLowerCase();
        
        // call replace() only if the character has a length > 1
        // after toLowerCase()
        n += c.length > 1 ? c.replace(/[^ -~]/g,'') : c;
    }
    return n;
}

console.log("gök" == to_lower("GÖK"));
console.log("hindi" == to_lower("HİNDİ"));

function to_low(s) // shorter version
{
    var n = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    { n += s[i].toLowerCase()[0]; }

    return n;
}

console.log("hindi" == to_low("HİNDİ"));
```

Comment: in this case ("gök" == "GÖK".toLowerCase().replace(/[^ -~]/g,'')) return false.

Comment: @serdem420 I edited my answer to make it works with all special characters like in your example.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your character `İ` is composed by 2 characters.

You have the `I` and then the 'dot' at the top (UTF-8 decimal code: 775).

Try this:

```js
"HİNDİ".toLocaleLowerCase().split('').map((_,v)=>console.log(_.charCodeAt(0)))
```

Compare it with this:

```js
"hindi".toLocaleLowerCase().split('').map((_,v)=>console.log(_.charCodeAt(0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. Is there any way to produce "true" for this kind of situations?

Comment: Yes, there is. But, it isn't a nice solution. You can remove every diacritic mark from your string and compare it.